# Pi-hole broken after upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04

Tags: dns

After distro upgrade to 20.04.1 from 18.04, my Pi-hole installation broke.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled Pi-hole, but the pihole DNS service won't start.

Console output [as a picture]:

[image: Console output]

Console output [in plain text]:

```
*** [ DIAGNOSING ]: Core version
[i] Core: v5.1.2 (https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/how-do-i-update-pi-hole/249)
[i] Remotes: origin     https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole.git (fetch)
             origin     https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole.git (push)
[i] Branch: master
[i] Commit: v5.1.2-0-g6b536b7

*** [ DIAGNOSING ]: Web version
[i] Web: v5.1.1 (https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/how-do-i-update-pi-hole/249)
[i] Remotes: origin     https://github.com/pi-hole/AdminLTE.git (fetch)
             origin     https://github.com/pi-hole/AdminLTE.git (push)
[i] Branch: master
[i] Commit: v5.1.1-0-ga03d1bd

*** [ DIAGNOSING ]: FTL version
[✓] FTL: v5.2
```

Comment: You have not said what version of Pihole you are running or how you are installing it. Any clues or output in your pihole log file (which may be `/var/log/pihole.log`) when you attempt to start it or restart the DNS service?

Comment: No info in the pihole.log - it's empty.  Added version info above.

Comment: Found the problem:pihole-FTL[1659]: dnsmasq: cannot access /etc/dnsmasq.d/lxd: No such file or directory removed symlink, seems to be working now.  https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/g86xo8/after_ubuntu_2004_upgrade_unable_to_start_dns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
> pihole-FTL[1659]: dnsmasq: cannot access /etc/dnsmasq.d/lxd: No such
> file or directory
```

I removed the `lxd` symlink and restarted it and it worked fine.

[Earlier solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/g86xo8/after_ubuntu_2004_upgrade_unable_to_start_dns/)